# VScode automaticly jumping on next page when doing a short break while typing

Tags: visual-studio-code

My VScode is jumping to the next line when writing code. It doesn't matter what or where I'm writing.
e.g:

```
export class FeatureModule{}
```

becomes

```
export class
FeatureModule{}
```

because I was thinking about the name for the module for a second...
It's extremly annoying and I can't find a setting that does the trick.
It also does not seems like it is any extension, because I have another PC where it does not happen and there I have the same Extensions.

Maybe there is a way to copy a "profile" with all settings and Extensions of the working VScode to the non-working one?

Cheers

Comment: You can try to open it with `--disable-extensions`, just to make sure..